# Springboot swagger ui with Bearer token

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I use Bearer token to access my api. so I configure my swagger just like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("br.com.lumera.intimacaoapi.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()));
    }


    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(
                "global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("Bearer",
                authorizationScopes));
    }
}
```

but for every request my user must input Bearer <>. It's possible to I configure the swagger to put automatic the  'Bearer ' before the token that my user insert?

tks

Answer (score 2):

One work around for this issue can be setting "Bearer " as default value as shown below

```
public ResponseEntity method_name(@ApiParam(defaultValue = "Bearer ") String auth) { }
```

This code will show "Bearer " as default value in token input field box. You can add the token after the bearer in the input field box.